# Export pandas Styled table to image file

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, pandas-styles

The code below when run in jupyter notebook renders a table with a colour gradient format that I would like to export to an image file.

The resulting 'styled_table' object that notebook renders is a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler type.

I have not been able to find a way to export the Styler to an image.

I hope someone can share a working example of an export, or give me some pointers.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {('count', 's25'): 
       {('2017-08-11', 'Friday'): 88.0,
        ('2017-08-12', 'Saturday'): 90.0,
        ('2017-08-13', 'Sunday'): 93.0},
        ('count', 's67'): 
       {('2017-08-11', 'Friday'): 404.0,
        ('2017-08-12', 'Saturday'): 413.0,
        ('2017-08-13', 'Sunday'): 422.0},
        ('count', 's74'): 
       {('2017-08-11', 'Friday'): 203.0,
        ('2017-08-12', 'Saturday'): 227.0,
        ('2017-08-13', 'Sunday'): 265.0},
        ('count', 's79'): 
       {('2017-08-11', 'Friday'): 53.0,
        ('2017-08-12', 'Saturday'): 53.0,
        ('2017-08-13', 'Sunday'): 53.0}}

table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
table.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)

cm = sns.light_palette("seagreen", as_cmap=True)
styled_table = table.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
styled_table
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358752/5741205)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png

Comment: My guess is that the last statement returns HTML code via [Styler.render](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html), so you need a Python way to convert HTML to an image, like [imgkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imgkit).

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `to_html()` method to obtain an HTML of the styled table (in old versions it was `render()`):

```
html = styled_table.to_html()
```

You can then use a package that converts html to an image. For example, [IMGKit: Python library of HTML to IMG wrapper](https://github.com/jarrekk/imgkit). Bear in mind that this solution requires the installation of [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), a command line tool to render HTML into PDF and various image formats. It is all described in the IMGKit page.

Once you have that, the rest is straightforward:

```
import imgkit
imgkit.from_string(html, 'styled_table.png')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org` do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @EnzoDtz it seems that either wkhtmltopdf is not installed, or that it is not accessible via the system path. You need to be able in a command line to enter e.g. `wkhtmltopdf --help` and see the help menu.

Comment: If others don't want to deal with installs, @Shovalt's process is available inside your browser with active Jupyter sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/dataframe2img), taking advantage of the MyBinder.org system.

Comment: I can find the pdf but not the image one of this executable

Comment: @thistleknot - I think it is the same executable. Just make sure that `wkhtmltopdf --help` works for you in the command line. If it doesn't work it means that you need to add the parent directory to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: that was the answer.  My jupyter was being run from a service and i used os.system(echo $PATH) and saw there was none despite seeing it myself with which(wkhtmltopdf).  So yeah, once I added environmentPath... yada yada to my .service file, jupyter picked up the path correctly.

Comment: ```Styler.render``` is deprecated since pandas 1.4.0, use ```Styler.to_html``` (from pandas 1.3.0 onward) instead.

Comment: @AttilatheFun, thanks, updated

Answer (score 21):

You can use dexplo's `dataframe_image` from https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image. After installing the package, it also lets you save styler objects as images like in this example from the `README`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,4))
df_styled = df.style.background_gradient()

dfi.export(df_styled, 'df_styled.png')
```

Comment: The previous answer was losing a lot of the formatting, this solution worked perfectly instead. Side note: I had to upgrade pip before I was able to install this package with `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: As of 2021, this should be the top answer. Compared to the `imgkit` solution, it mimics Jupyter's style and doesn't require external dependencies.

Comment: The doesn't render the LaTeX in my styled `DataFrame`.

Comment: As alluded to by @James Hirschorn, `dataframe_image` seems designed to work only with the HTML representation of Styler (which is relevant to OP since Jupyter uses the HTML), not any other output method currently available (e.g., Excel, LaTeX). The way to get those things to an image will be very different from the way to get HTML to an image. One option for pdfLaTeX is to then use, say, ```pdf2image.convert_from_path(...)``` to get a list of pillow images and ```image.save(filepath, 'PNG')``` to save each one.