# Convert pandas.io.formats.style.Styler to image file

Tags: css, pandas, seaborn, pandas-styles

I am creating a conditional formatting table in Python using pandas and seaborn which gives me a pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object. I need to export this as an image file .

I cannot use imgkit, unable to install wkhtmltopdf.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns

    iris = pd.read_excel('iris.xlsx')
    iris.head()

    cm = sns.diverging_palette(240, 10, sep=20, as_cmap=True)
    sample = iris.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm)
    sample
```

Comment: But you did understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664519/export-pandas-styled-table-to-image-file ?

Comment: I understood the answer to that. I specifically mentioned that I cannot install wkhtml2pdf so I cannot use imgkit. I am looking for an alternate solution.