# Convert a styled dataframe to an image in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a number of styled dataframes (using `df.style`), how would I go about converting this to an image.

If I try and save these down using:

```
df_styled.savefig('/u1/username/df_styled.png')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export pandas Styled table to image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664519/export-pandas-styled-table-to-image-file)

Comment: I've tried this but get the following error:
OSError: 
No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "command not found"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it.
Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org

Comment: Then install wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I have it installed already which is why its strange. Do you know what it means by "No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "command not found"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it."?

Comment: It means that is not installed, or cannot be found. Check if you can use wkhtmltoimage commands from the command line, verify if all paths are set correctly, or ask a new question.