# Python suddenly stopped when matplot image was drawn

Tags: python, django

Python suddenly stopped when matplot image was drawn.
I wanna show matplot image's table in index.html.Now I wrote in views.py

```
def past_result(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'chart': _view_plot(request)})

def _view_plot(request):
    dates = [20150805,20160902,20170823]
    heights = [5,6,3]

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['DATE'] = dates
    df['SCORE'] = heights

    col_width = 3.0
    row_height = 0.625
    font_size = 14
    header_color = '#40466e'
    row_colors = ['#f1f1f2', 'w']
    edge_color = 'w'
    bbox = [0, 0, 1, 1]
    header_columns = 0
    ax = None

    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(df.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=df.columns)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0] % len(row_colors)])
            plt.show()
    return ax
```

in index.html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ chart }}" width="700px" height="500px" alt="RESULT"/>
```

When I read past_result method,Python suddenly stopped .I do not know why.Why does such a error happen? I read this url as reference 
[How to save the Pandas dataframe/series data as a figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726663/how-to-save-the-pandas-dataframe-series-data-as-a-figure)       .How should I fix this?

```
Traceback is
** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc96b737b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffde4b348d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc96bc082 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fffcb103ce0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fffcb08e3b3 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 170
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fffc711e8bd -[NSApplication run] + 1200
    6   _macosx.so                          0x000000010509c8d2 init_macosx + 32564
    7   Python                              0x00000001000c4fd5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 31605
    8   Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    9   Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    10  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    11  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    12  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    13  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    14  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    15  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    16  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    17  Python                              0x00000001000c2198 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19768
    18  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    19  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    20  Python                              0x00000001000c540f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32687
    21  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    22  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    23  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    24  Python                              0x00000001000c2198 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19768
    25  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    26  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    27  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    28  Python                              0x00000001000c2198 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19768
    29  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    30  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    31  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    32  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    33  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    34  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    35  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    36  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    37  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    38  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    39  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    40  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    41  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    42  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    43  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    44  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    45  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    46  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    47  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    48  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    49  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    50  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    51  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    52  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    53  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    54  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    55  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    56  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    57  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    58  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    59  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    60  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    61  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    62  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    63  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    64  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    65  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    66  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    67  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    68  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    69  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    70  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    71  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    72  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    73  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    74  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    75  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    76  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    77  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    78  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    79  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    80  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    81  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    82  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    83  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    84  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    85  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    86  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    87  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    88  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    89  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    90  Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    91  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    92  Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    93  Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    94  Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    95  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    96  Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    97  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    98  Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    99  Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    100 Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    101 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    102 Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    103 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    104 Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    105 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    106 Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    107 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    108 Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    109 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    110 Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    111 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    112 Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    113 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    114 Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    115 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    116 Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    117 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    118 Python                              0x000000010007a44a slot_tp_call + 74
    119 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    120 Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    121 Python                              0x00000001000c540f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32687
    122 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    123 Python                              0x00000001000c52cd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32365
    124 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    125 Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    126 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    127 Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    128 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    129 Python                              0x000000010007a078 slot_tp_init + 88
    130 Python                              0x0000000100075ea5 type_call + 245
    131 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    132 Python                              0x00000001000bfc73 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10259
    133 Python                              0x00000001000c540f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32687
    134 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    135 Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    136 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    137 Python                              0x00000001000c2198 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 19768
    138 Python                              0x00000001000c540f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32687
    139 Python                              0x00000001000c540f PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 32687
    140 Python                              0x00000001000c7ff3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2131
    141 Python                              0x000000010003e1e0 function_call + 176
    142 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    143 Python                              0x000000010001ec2d instancemethod_call + 365
    144 Python                              0x000000010000c442 PyObject_Call + 98
    145 Python                              0x00000001000bc1a7 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 87
    146 Python                              0x0000000100106897 t_bootstrap + 71
    147 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdefb19af _pthread_body + 180
    148 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdefb18fb _pthread_body + 0
    149 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffdefb1101 thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What does exactly means the `Python suddenly stopped` ? There should be a slacktrace, an error shown somewhere...

Comment: @ClémentDenoix I added traceback in my question

Comment: I was expecting the stacktrace from the django development server... Where do you call the django view ?