# Setting cell color of matplotlib table and save as a figure?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following this code [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39358752/9006421)!  to save a table as the image, and I have some feature like check value in a cell then set color for a cell, but I added some code stylemap, it doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six
.........



df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['2016-04-01', '2016-04-02', '2016-04-03']
df['calories'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df['sleep hours'] = [2200, 2100, 1500]
df['gym'] = [True, False, False]
df.style.applymap(color)
render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0)

.......
def color(val):
    if val < datetime.now():
        color = 'green'
    elif val > datetime.now():
        color = 'yellow'
    elif val > (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)):
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                 header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                 bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                 ax=None, **kwargs):
if ax is None:
    size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
    ax.axis('off')

mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
    cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
    if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
        cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
        cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
    else:
        cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
return ax
```

I put style under dataframe then render
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5xoF.png)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create new dataframe for Cell Colors, create the dataFrame with colors checked those values in table, then add to `cellColours`
My code block:

```
#table datas
df = pd.DataFrame()
members = [x.display_name[:10] for x in message.server.members]
arrayDataFrame(members, 'Players', df)
arrayDataFrame(Data=members, df=df)
#table Colors
cf = pd.DataFrame()
arrayColorFrame(members, "Players", cf)
arrayColorFrame(Data=members, df=cf)
#render
plt = render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0, col_width=2.0, CellCol= cf)

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                 header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'W'], edge_color='B',
                 bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                 ax=None, CellCol=None, **kwargs):
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
      mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns,
            cellColours=CellCol.values, **kwargs)


def arrayDataFrame(Data, Lable='No', df=None):
    if df is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    leng = len(Data)
    array = list()
    if Lable == 'No':
        for index in range(leng):
            array.append(int(index + 1))
    else:
        for val in Data:
            array.append(val)
    df[Lable] = array
    return df

def arrayColorFrame(Data, Lable='No', df=None):
    if df is None:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
    leng = len(Data)
    array = list()
    if Lable == 'No':
        for index in range(leng):
            val = index + 1
            if val < 10:
                color = 'green'
            elif val < 20:
                color = 'yellow'
            elif val < 40:
                color = 'red'
            else:
                color = 'w'
            array.append(color)
    else:
        for val in Data:
            if "nat" in val :
                color = 'blue'
            else:
                color='w'
            array.append(color)
    df[Lable] = array
    return df
```

[Result testing in discord python : Picture](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/443920423030095873/529283002174537794/Hello.png)