# How to turn Pandas output into an image for download?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[I want to turn this image, which is an output, into an image for download.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3rIe.png)

Other tutorials on turning it into a matplotlib table have not worked at all.
And yes I could use snipping tool but I want it to export an image like you can in matplotlib.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726663/how-to-save-the-pandas-dataframe-series-data-as-a-figure

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).