# How to plot discrete f(x,y) output

Tags: python, plot

I have a function f(x,y) written in python 3 which takes integer input and outputs either 1 or 0.

My plan is to illustrate this function with black and white squares on a square grid, but i have no idea of how to do it. What could i do?

Comment: could you use matplotlib?

Comment: I think you should look into `matplotlib` module [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194482/custom-matplotlib-plot-chess-board-like-table-with-colored-cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot a grid of data with matplotlib use imshow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
    return (x+y)%2

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=True)

zz = f(xx,yy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(zz,interpolation='none',cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

If your f is more complex, you have to vectorize it first:

```
f = np.vectorize(f)
```